# Transform to visual-format of Auto-Layout

Tags: objective-c, constraints, transform, autolayout

Does anyone could help me to transform this code into visual-format auto-layout? 
I've tried several ways but I can't do this...
Thank you!

```
// Constraints
horizontal = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:loginView.view
                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                             toItem:nil
                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                         multiplier:1.0
                                           constant:CGRectGetWidth(loginView.view.frame)];

vertical = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:loginView.view
                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                           toItem:nil
                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                       multiplier:1.0
                                         constant:CGRectGetHeight(loginView.view.frame)];

centerX = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:loginView.view
                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                           toItem:self.view
                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                       multiplier:1.0
                                         constant:0.0];

centerY = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:loginView.view
                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                          toItem:self.view
                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                      multiplier:1.0
                                        constant:0.0];

[self.view addConstraints:@[horizontal, vertical, centerX, centerY]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally!

```
// Variables
NSDictionary *views = @{
                        @"view" : self.view,
                        @"superview" : self.view.superview,
                        };
NSDictionary *metrics = @{
                          @"width" : @(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame)),
                          @"height" : @(CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame))
                          };

// Constraints
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[superview]-(<=1)-[view(width)]"
                                                               options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                                               metrics:metrics
                                                                 views:views];
[self.view.superview addConstraints:constraints];

constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[superview]-(<=1)-[view(height)]"
                                                      options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX
                                                      metrics:metrics
                                                        views:views];
[self.view.superview addConstraints:constraints];
```